# Horizontal website navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in planning stage for a site, which needs to scroll horizontally.

The simplest solution I have to tackle this is to go in this direction, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsRCS/).

I'm not sure if this is the best option, as I will have to arrange each div individually i.e. `left: 100%` `left: 200%;`.

Is there a way around the divs, with a `display: inline-block` value auto wrapping to the viewport, so I don't have to arrange each div individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Removing the absolute positioning

What you need to do here is remove the `float` and absolute positioning from your dividers and simply add `white-space: nowrap` to your `body`. As your dividers are set to display as `inline-block`, these get affected by the `white-space` property.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;  padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/MsRCS/1/)**.

### Removing the spaces between each block

Now that we've removed the floats and the positioning, you'll notice that there is a white space between each divider. If we refer to [this CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), we can remove this by simply giving the `body` a `font-size` of 0, and giving each divider a `font-size` of what you're wanting the font size to be within those blocks:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;  padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:0;
}

.full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

[**Second JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/MsRCS/5/).

Comment: @Zemljoradnik good shout, for some reason JSFiddle skipped right over the third revision of that fiddle and went straight to the 4th revision. I've fixed the link. :)

Comment: Great, will save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MsRCS/3/

You can remove the absolute positioning and use float instead.

```
body {
    margin: 0;  padding: 0;
    width:300%;
}

.full {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

}

#screen-1 {
    background: red;    
}

#screen-2 {
    background: blue;
}

#screen-3 {
    background: yellow;
}
```